# whatId when using custom object

Tags: email-template

I am having an html email template which uses certain merge fields from a custom object. Now I am using following apex code to send certain emails to users.

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

        mail.setTargetObjectId(t.OwnerId); 
        mail.setTemplateId(et.Id);
        mail.setWhatId(t.Id); 
        mail.SaveAsActivity = false;
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.singleemailMessage[] {mail});
```

Code is saved without error but when I run it it says "can't use whatId when sending email to users". Can anyone explain me how to overcome this error? When I use a visualforce template then same code works fine.

Answer (score 43):

Unfortunately, the above solutions, to send to a contact record or to `setToAddresses`, will count towards Salesforce limit as explained here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_email.htm

> You can send an unlimited amount of email to your org’s internal users, which includes portal users.

Internal user means the proper user record, not a random email address or Contact.

A solution which allows to send email to internal user, and yet allows the use of the whatId is by leveraging `Messaging.renderStoredEmailTemplate(templateId, whoId, whatId)`. Click here for more details on this method: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_messaging.htm. This method allows to merge the fields without sending an email. Once fields are merged, it's possible to retrieve the subject and body text of the merged template and send an email to internal users without specifying a whatId.

Ultimately, this is what needs to be done

```
String templateId = ....;
String userId = ....;
String whatId = ....;

Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = Messaging.renderStoredEmailTemplate(templateId, userId, whatId);

String emailSubject = email.getSubject();
String emailTextBody = email.getPlainTextBody();

email.setTargetObjectId(userId);
email.setSubject(emailSubject);
email.setPlainTextBody(emailTextBody);
email.saveAsActivity = false;

if(!Test.isRunningTest()) {
  Messaging.SendEmailResult[] r = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email});
}
```

Comment: This is a very elegant solution to this problem. Thanks Sir.

Comment: This is perfect solution I was always looking for. Why haven't I found this ever before!

Comment: This is the perfect solution to this problem. It should be marked as best answer in my opinion.

Comment: You should be able  to get rid of the Subject/Body stuff.  I was able to make this work with just these lines:
`        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = Messaging.renderStoredEmailTemplate(templateId, userId, recordId);
        message.setTargetObjectId(userId);
        message.setSaveAsActivity(false);
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] messages = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> {message};
        
        Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results = Messaging.sendEmail(messages);`

Comment: You saved my life! I had to send an email to several email addresses but not to the user, and `renderStoredEmailTemplate` worked! I wasted a day on it.....

Answer (score 24):

This is a glaring hole that I'm sad to say has been here since the beginning.  Particular frustrating since workflow alerts seem to have no problems merging a custom object template when sending to a user.  You can work around it by creating a contact with the users email and then deleting it after the email has been sent.

```
private static void sendMyTemplate(Id userId, Id mergedObjectId) {
  User user = [select email, firstName, lastName from User where id = :userId];
  Contact tempContact = new Contact(email = user.email, firstName = user.firstName, lastName = user.lastName);
  insert tempContact;
  Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
  mail.setTargetObjectId(tempContact.id); 
  mail.setTemplateId(template.Id);
  mail.setWhatId(mergedObjectId); 
  Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.singleemailMessage[] {mail});
  delete tempContact;
}
```

Comment: Ralph, plus 1 for a creative idea.

Comment: The one glaring whole is validation rules.  If you're org creates a new contact validation rule it'll break this code ... in which case @LaceySnr suggestion will be a better route

Comment: +1. Though not recommended approach, but one of way out solution as of now. Thanks Ralph!

Comment: What about if there are some business process - email notification, external system integration when contact is created :)

Answer (score 14):

You can get around this by grabbing the user's email address from their user record (you've already got their ID so that's a trivial query) and then using that with the `setToAddresses` method of `SingleEmailMessage`, then you shouldn't need to set the target object ID and as such will bypass this restriction.

Comment: The downside to this approach is you can't use any merge fields dependent on the target object id.

Comment: Did this ever work for you?  Was just trying this and I get a dml error.  Posted a question about it: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/23273/594

Comment: It did for me... will see if I can check it out tomorrow, pushed for time right now!

Comment: Thanks @laceysnr, really hoping I don't have to always waste two DML statements creating and deleting a contact.

Comment: I tried this, but I get this error: `First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Missing targetObjectId with template: []`

Comment: Even I tried this and getting the error. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Missing targetObjectId with template:

Comment: Six years later, still an issue.  Ugh.  Regarding this solution - doesn't this have the side effect that the email will apply to the daily email limits, whereas email sent to a User or Contact does not?  @RalphCallaway's solution should avoid that.  I should probably use a VF template, but I know the end users will want control of the email template.

Answer (score 10):

It would seem that you can't set the WhatId (which you have) when the target object Id is a UserId. You can set it when the target is a contact or such. 
This post i found seems to confirm that hunch 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11105086/setwhatid-in-salesforce-using-email-template

Comment: Note that it does work in visualforce email templates as @doga mentioned. It's a rather arbitrary restriction on non-VF templating.