# Can't set toAddresses on email when templateId defined?

Tags: apex, email, email-template, singleemailmessage

#### Question

Did something change recently with the SingleEmail methods that prevents using setToAddresses() when a template is used?

#### Background

I need to send an email to a user based and pass in the related record.  However, you can't set `targetObjectId` to a user id if `whatId` has been set.

There used to be two known workarounds.  First, to create a contact with the desired email address and use that for `targetObjectId`.  Second, don't set `targetObjectId` and instead set `toAddresses` to the target user's email (see [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/1825/594)).  However, the docs seem to state this is no longer possible.

> setToAddresses(String[]) Optional. A list of email addresses to which
>   you are sending the email. The maximum number of email addresses
>   allowed is 100. This argument is allowed only when a template is not
>   used.
>   via [apex docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_Messaging_SingleEmailMessage_instance_methods.htm)

I'm really hoping to avoid creating a dummy contact for this since we have a lot of triggers on that object.  Am I taking crazy pills and it was never actually possible to use `toAddresses` with `templateId` or is this a recent change?  If it's a recent change is there any other workaround?

#### Desired Usage

```
public static void send(Id recordId, Id templateId, String toAddress) {
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    email.setWhatId(recordId);
    email.setTemplateId(templateId);
    email.setToAddresses(new String[] { toAddress });
    Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { email });
}
```

#### Resulting Error Message

> System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0;
>   first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Missing targetObjectId with
>   template: []

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using Newly introduced method `setTreatTargetObjectAsRecipient()` in Winter 16, you can send email message to any email address.

```
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    email.setWhatId(recordId);
    email.setTemplateId(templateId);
    email.setToAddresses(new String[] { toAddress });   

    //Set current user as target object 
    email.settargetObjectId(UserInfo.getUserId()); 
    email.setsaveAsActivity(false);

    //This method would make sure email will not be sent to user
    email.setTreatTargetObjectAsRecipient(false); 
    Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { email });
```

Comment: Ishwar, might be worth mentioning which Release and API version this new method is available in.

Answer (score 2):

I am fairly certain that you have always been required to use a templateId and targetObjectId in tandem. All of my code that sends an email using a template requires a contact to be associated to the email, and I am fairly certain that this was because the system required this condition when I wrote the code a few years back. The problem is that without a targetObjectId, the template can't merge contact fields correctly, so they probably made this restriction intentionally.

You don't need to use a contact, though, as leads are also acceptable targets. If your leads are less burdened than contacts are, you might simply choose to create a new lead instead (but then you can't set a "what id", such as an opportunity). In any event, you could *probably* just patch your triggers to ignore any contacts created when a certain flag is true, and use a @future method to (hard) delete the contact once the email has been sent. Of course, if you have installed packages, this may not be feasible.

Comment: thanks for the confirmation, still don't understand why they haven't fixed it to where you can user users and the template.  They're fine with you not setting whatId with a template, but enforcing the user piece is strange.  Big hole :(

Comment: not to mention confusing seeing as workflows alerts have no problems with users as targets

Answer (score 1):

I think it has always been that way. One work around could be to create a temporary contact and use that to send the email. (Haven't tested it, though)

Comment: @sfdcfox What if we want to use a template that is not based on contact/lead object -- n due to this targetObjectId -referring only user/lead, we are unable to establish a context for this template we want?  What would be your suggestion in such case.