# Custom Button to Send an email using email template

Tags: javascript, custom-button, send-email

I have created a custom button on Opportunity. The custom button has following javascript code. When the user clicks on the button the email should be sent.I find no errors in the code. But I am not able to send any emails.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/connection.js")}
(function() {
sforce.connection.sessionId = "{!$Api.Session_ID}";
var message = new sforce.SingleEmailMessage();
message.replyTo = "varunreddypenna@gmail.com,varunrp@okstate.edu";
message.targetObjectId = "{!Opportunity.Id}";
message.templateId = "00Xj0000000J8sI";
var result = sforce.connection.sendEmail([message]);
  if(result[0].success) {
     alert("I sent the email as you requested, master.");
  } else {
     alert("I had a booboo.");
  }
}());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran this code and result is not quite what you think.

If you `alert` the whole result object, you get this:

```
{errors:{message:'Only Users, Contact, Lead or Person objects are allowed for targetObjectId : a0SK000000FtD7J.', statusCode:'INVALID_TYPE_FOR_OPERATION', targetObjectId:null, }, success:'false', }
```

Your code needs to look like this to actually work:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/connection.js")}
(function() {
sforce.connection.sessionId = "{!$Api.Session_ID}";
var message = new sforce.SingleEmailMessage();
message.replyTo = "rapsac@gmail.com";
message.targetObjectId = "005K0000002butj";
message.templateId = "00XK0000000QsbW";
message.saveAsActivity = false;
var result = sforce.connection.sendEmail([message]);
  if(result[0].success == 'true') {
     alert("I sent the email as you requested, master.");
  } else {
     alert("I had a booboo.");
  }
alert(result);
}());
```

There were several other errors too - the key is to output the whole error in an alert so you can debug it.

As you can see, the `targetObjectId` is the user that the email is going to, not the object that the template refers to.

Also, `saveAsActivity` needs to be false to send to an internal user.

This is probably going to take quite a bit of work to get going, but hopefully you are now on the right track.

Comment: You did mention targetObjectid with a value. May I know what id value is that? I would like to do this any opportunity record. So in this I cannot mention each and every value in targetObjectid. So is there any way to do that. 
Thank you.

Comment: I'm investigating...

Comment: So far the answer by @ralf callaway is the best work around I've seen: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1816/whatid-when-using-custom-object - his example is in apex, but it's easily convertable to javascript