# WhatId Is Not Available For Sending Emails To UserIds

Tags: apex, email-template

I am getting the error - WhatId Is Not Available For Sending Emails To UserIds while trying to send email to user from an Apex Trigger using SingleMailMessage.

The code is working absolutely fine with a predefined standard EMail Template but the only problem is - it is unable to produce values of Merge Fields from the Custom Object that I wanted to set as whatId.

Any idea how to get rid of this error? As an alternative I might need to set the htmlBody of the mail in code but I am not sure.in that case how I can use the background layout that (it has some custom pink color and images set with company logo in the mail background)I had set in my email template?

```
   List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> eMail = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>(); 
   for (Event__c ea : eaList)
   {                   
    Set<String> invitedBy= new Set<String>();
    List<String> sendTo = new List<String>();  
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage singleMail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

    invitedBy.add(ea.CreatedBy.Email);       // to capture unique values
    sendTo.addAll(invitedBy);
    singleMail.setToAddresses(sendTo);

    singleMail.setReplyTo('xxxx@gmail.com');
    singleMail.setSenderDisplayName('xxxx');
    singleMail.setTargetObjectId(ea.CreatedById);

    //set template Id
    singleMail.setTemplateId(et.Id);
    singleMail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
    // singleMail.setWhatId(ea.Parent_event_c);  // gives error WhatId Is Not Available For Sending Emails To UserIds
    eMail.add(singleMail);
}
Messaging.sendEmail(eMail);
```

I tried to follow the link - [whatId when using custom object](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1816/whatid-when-using-custom-object)
and changed the code...but here I ended up doing DML (inserting contact) within for loop..any idea how to avoid this ?

```
 List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> eMail = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>(); 
   for (Event__c ea : eaList)
   {                   
    Set<String> invitedBy= new Set<String>();
    List<String> sendTo = new List<String>();  
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage singleMail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

 // insert the mail id as a contact as suggested in the link 
tc = new Contact(email = ea.CreatedBy.Email, firstName = ea.CreatedBy.Name ,lastName = ea.CreatedBy.Name);
    insert tc ;
    invitedBy.add(tc.Email);       // to capture unique values
    sendTo.addAll(invitedBy);
    singleMail.setToAddresses(sendTo);

    singleMail.setReplyTo('xxxx@gmail.com');
    singleMail.setSenderDisplayName('xxxx');
    singleMail.setTargetObjectId(ea.CreatedById);

    //set template Id
    singleMail.setTemplateId(et.Id);
    singleMail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
    // singleMail.setWhatId(ea.Parent_event_c);  // gives error WhatId Is Not Available For Sending Emails To UserIds
    eMail.add(singleMail);
}
Messaging.sendEmail(eMail);
//delete the contact once email sent
delete tc;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the documentation:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm

> If you specify a contact for the targetObjectId field, you can specify
>   an optional whatId as well. This helps to further ensure that merge
>   fields in the template contain the correct data

So, since the targetObjectID field is not a contact, you cannot specify a WhatID.

There are some workarounds using a VF email template:

http://www.forcedisturbances.com/2012/04/automatically-sending-email-reminders.html

Or, you could on the fly create a contact for the user, use that, then delete the contact.

[whatId when using custom object](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1816/whatid-when-using-custom-object)

Comment: Hi @ Eric, yes per documentation its correct , but there is an excellent workaround given here - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1816/whatid-when-using-custom-object ..Now , my problem is following this logic I ended up in doing DML inside the loop which I should avoid..

Comment: Seems like you can go aruond this limitation if you use the Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = Messaging.renderStoredEmailTemplate(template.Id, whoId, whatId); -- worth trying