# ASK - Field value is blank in Apex single email (HTML Template)

Tags: apex, email, email-template, class, singleemailmessage

My case is i want to send email with attachment in custom object using single email message using HTML Email Template (with letterhead).

Current condition i successed to make the email same like email template (HTML body) by using these methods:

```
email.setToAddresses(emailResults);
email.setTargetObjectId('0055D000001DHyJ'); //user id
email.setTreatTargetObjectAsRecipient(false);
email.setTemplateId(tem.Id);
```

But the problem is, fields in email template become blank.
For Example:

**Email template**

> Dear {!Invoice__c.Customer},

**Result**

> Dear ,

**I also try use .replace but it make email body become blank.**

Is there any solution or workaround for this case?

Refference : http://hareeshgoudsalesforce.blogspot.com/2016/06/stop-sending-email-to-settargetobjectid.html

Comment: Is the `setTargetObjectId` being set to a `User` or `Contact` or `Lead` ?

Comment: Hi, its working now. I post the code at 2nd answer below. So for custom object you should put setTargetObjectId as ContactId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure exactly what your goal is and the blog post is very confusing to me.

What I understand is: `{!Invoice__c.Customer}` needs to be filled in the result.

For this case, the WhatId should be of Type `Invoice__c` and you should be using the appropriate template methods:

`email.setToAddresses(emailResults);
email.setTargetObjectId('0a3xxxxxx'); //<= user / recipient id
email.setWhatId('0a3xxxxxx'); // <= Invoice Id
email.setTreatTargetObjectAsRecipient(false);
email.setTemplateId(tem.Id);`

> [setWhatId(WhatI)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm#apex_Messaging_SingleEmailMessage_setWhatId)
>
> If you specify a contact for the targetObjectId field, you can specify an optional whatId as well. This helps to further ensure that merge fields in the template contain the correct data.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your respond. I try to replace using Invoice ID in setTargetObjectId but it give error message "SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_TYPE_FOR_OPERATION, Only User, Contact, Lead, or Person objects are allowed for targetObjectId: a045D000009HDVm.: [targetObjectId, a045D000009HDVmQAO]"

Comment: My goal is want to fill the fields in HTML Email template using single email message, .setReplace() not working for this case :(

Comment: sorry, i mixed something up. see my edited answer.

Comment: Now i get this error 'SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_ID_FIELD, WhatId is not available for sending emails to UserIds.: [whatId, a045D000009HDVm]'. FYI i write email.setWhatId(d.id)

Comment: Well, then use a contactId for your test :) also please see this question: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/81499/whatid-is-not-available-for-sending-emails-to-userids

Comment: Updated: I input TargetObjectId as ContactId and input WhatId as CustomObjectId. And its work bro, thanks for your help. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

```
email.setToAddresses(emailResults);
 email.setTargetObjectId('0035D00000Rc4bU'); //contact id (you can do soql)
 email.setWhatId(d.id); // custom object id
 email.setTreatTargetObjectAsRecipient(false);
 email.setTemplateId(tem.Id);
```

Updated : Final solution