# Flow - Add Related Record ID into Send Email Action/Add User into related user in email alert

Tags: visual-workflow, email-alert

I'm using flow to send email which need to contain the related quote records link and some merge fields. However, when i added the recrod.id into the related record id field in send email action, the system gives me the error as attached.

[image: flow error screenshot]
Also, i'm not able to use the send email alert function as the appointed recipient is defined in a field "Next Approver" in quote and it's dynamic, while the " Next Approver" is not selectable as recipient in the email alert.
[image: email alert screenshot]

Can anyone help me on solving this? i need to have the recipient as the value dynamically assigned in the next approver field and in the meantime have the record link display in the email notification. Thank you

Comment: Does [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/81499/whatid-is-not-available-for-sending-emails-to-userids) help with some of the question?