# Classic Email Template doesn't transfer merge fields within a Flow?

Tags: administration, developer

I have a use case where I'm creating a reminder email for an approval process. We have a custom solution from a 3rd party so I'm unable to re-create the email template used. The Approval process has 21 steps with different users being the approvers so I can't create 21 clones of an email alert...I mean I can but that's an outdates solution.

So instead, I'm using a flow action to send an email and using the email template id so it can be used within the email action to reference the classic email template in question...the issue comes in when the email is being sent out, the merge fields like **{!TM_TOMA__Agreement__c.Agreement_Name__c}** aren't being shown when the email is sent from the flow. So I decided to try and use a format that flow understands in the template itself and put **{!$Record.Agreement_Name__c}** but it didn't recognize that either...

Is there a solution to this or do I have to create 21 email alerts? haha

[image]

Comment: Please use [edit] and show how you've configured the Flow send email action.

Comment: Done! Sorry about that, I should've included that.

Comment: Merge fields won't appear without the related record Id being the ID of the `TM_TOMA_Agreement__c` object

Comment: But the Agreement object is the one this flow is setup in, it's not a related object...or Salesforce just makes things complicated and confusing for no reason? lol

Comment: I added the id of the Agreement object and it yelled this at me -                           
 Error Occurred:

WhatId is not available for sending emails to UserIds. Invalid entity type for whatId.

Comment: perhaps some help here in [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/81515/2602); there's also the UnofficialSf.com `Send Better Email` action to look into

Comment: I take it "Merge fields won't appear without the related record Id being the ID of the TM_TOMA_Agreement__c object" was an incorrect statement then?

Comment: no - it is true -- just that when sending to a User, that option is forsworn.