# Send email using apex with merge fields from a custom object in the email template

Tags: apex, email, email-template

This appears to be a simple use case that I can't figure out.

I want to send email to a list of UserIDs based on an HTML or VisualForce email template. The email template could look something like this:

```
Dear User,

Please have a look at the following Data Extract Request:

{!Data_Extract_Request__c.Request_Title__c}
```

Naturally, this template needs a reference to a Data Extract Request object. However, I have no idea how to do this with Apex. I was expecting something like the following in Apex:

```
Messaging.MassEmailMessage email = new Messaging.MassEmailMessage();
email.setTargetObjectIds(userIds);
email.setWhatIds(dataExtractRequestIds); //Apparently, I can't do this
email.setTemplateId(templateId);
email.setSaveAsActivity(false);
Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.MassEmailMessage[] {email});
```

Unfortunately, it looks like there is no way to set to pass a custom object to an email template through apex. Is there a workaround to this problem? Or is there something I'm missing?

EDIT:

I have tried doing this through SingleMailMessage as well. The code is below:

```
List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emailsToSend = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
for (integer i=0; i<whatIds.size(); i++) {
  Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
  email.setTargetObjectId(targetObjectIds[i]);
  email.setTreatTargetObjectAsRecipient(true);
  email.setWhatId(whatIds[i]);
  email.setTemplateId(templateId);
  email.setSaveAsActivity(false);
  emailsToSend.add(email);
}
Messaging.sendEmail(emailsToSend);
```

I get the following exception:

System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_ID_FIELD, WhatId is not available for sending emails to UserIds.

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/144498 Above solution is clean approach

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/144498 This is optimal solution for this problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by adding the messages, indivudually, to a list

```
List<Messaging. MassEmailMessage > messagesToSend = new List<Messaging. MassEmailMessage>();

        for (Id objectId : dataExtractRequestIds) {
            Messaging. MassEmailMessage mail = new Messaging. MassEmailMessage();

            mail.setTargetObjectIds(userIds);
            mail.setTreatTargetObjectAsRecipient(true);

            mail.setTemplateId(templateId);
            mail.setwhatId(objectId);
            mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);

            messagesToSend.adD(mail);
        }

        Messaging.sendEmail(messagesToSend);
```

You can absolutely pass a custom object.

a) Ensure your header looks like the one I put below (change the subject, of course)

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="the Sibject" recipientType="User" relatedToType="Data_Extract_Request__c">
```

b) Then, on your merge fields, use this notation

```
{!RelatedTo.Request_Title__c}
```

Comment: That's interesting. I'll test this and let you know.

Comment: That did indeed execute. And my email was successfully sent. But unfortunately, the merge fields are empty. Why might that be?

Comment: I am assuming you checked that the ObjectId points to the correct object? If so, please update your original post with the entire template (include the headers)...

Comment: The empty merge fields were a fault on my part .. I had missed setting WhatId at all. I have updated the question with the current problem I'm facing.

Comment: it is possible to do what you need. I am updating my sample

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I have updated the question as well. 

From the following link, all I can get is that it's not possible to pass a custom object record to an email template. setWhatId only supports a few standard objects and setTargetObjectId only supports contacts, leads and users. https://goo.gl/5UJZIj

Comment: Ah, I think I see what the problem is. I need to use a ContactId instead of a UserId to be able to use the WhatId field?

Comment: Nope. Look at the whatId again. The last bullet is "Custom". The code I added above was copy-pasted from a project where this is working fine. Give it a shot and you'll see it works

Comment: By the way, I ended up using a SingleEmailMessage in a List, passing a ContactID instead of UserID. I'll paste the updated code as an answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

Using information from Sebastian Kessel's answer, I was able to do this with the following code:

```
List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emailsToSend = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
for (integer i=0; i<whatIds.size(); i++) {
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    email.setTargetObjectId(targetObjectIds[i]);
    email.setTreatTargetObjectAsRecipient(true);
    email.setWhatId(whatIds[i]);
    email.setTemplateId(templateId);
    email.setSaveAsActivity(false);
    emailsToSend.add(email);
}

Messaging.sendEmail(emailsToSend);
```

The important point is that TargetObjectIds *have* to be contacts for WhatId to work.