# For setWhatId i am unable to assign custom object record id

Tags: massemailmessage

HI friends for setWhatId i am unable to assign custom object record id. I am getting following exception. caused by: System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_ID_FIELD, Only contracts, cases, products and opportunities allowed for whatIds.: []

That means we can not use custom object records as merge fields ?. Its really bad from salesforce.

[whatId when using custom object](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1816/whatid-when-using-custom-object/154164#154164)

Comment: FYI [Mass email message giving whatids error on custom object](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000AwTjIAK).

Answer (score 2):

If you're sending the mass email to a list of contacts, what you describe is in the Apex documentation under [MassEmailMessage Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_mass.htm%23apex_Messaging_MassEmailMessage_setWhatIds):

> **setWhatIds(whatIds)**
>
> Optional. If you specify a list of contacts for the targetObjectIds field, you can specify a list of whatIds as well. This helps to further ensure that merge fields in the template contain the correct data.
>
> **Signature**
>
> public Void setWhatIds(ID[] whatIds)
>
> **Parameters**
>
> *whatIds*
>
> Type: ID[]
>
> **Return Value**
>
> Type: Void
>
> **Usage**
>
> The values must be one of the following types:
>
> - Contract
> - Case
> - Opportunity
> - Product

Comment: i must admit, I find this restriction to be inexplicable

Comment: @cropredy I don't write the documentation, I just regurgitate it. ;)

Comment: looks like its better to use SingleEmailMessage  . Here for setWhatId(whatId)  i can use custom objects too.The value must be one of the following types:

Account
Asset
Campaign
Case
Contract
Opportunity
Order
Product
Solution
Custom

Comment: @makk That would be correct. The only way to do what you want is to use SingleEmailMessaging methods, not MassEmail Methods