# Make merge fields work inside the email template in for loops

Tags: apex, batch, email-template, singleemailmessage

I have a requirement where I am sending email via batch class. I have created an email template and I want to send data to the merge fields of the template from the code that I am writing.
Since the mail will be sent for more than 1 record so I am using a for loop for the Messaging.SingleEmailMessage.
The issue is with the HTMLBody component. In the for loop I am observing that the HTMLBody is iterating but the merge fields are not getting captured accordingly. This implies I am receiving email for all the expected records but the email content keeps repeating only for the first record.
Please let me know how will I be able to send the email for all the concerned records and the email template will have the data accordingly.

Below is the part of the email code that I have been writing :-

```
for(Test__c res : finalResourceEmailList){
            htmlBody = htmlBody.replace('{!Test__c.Name}', res.Name);
            htmlBody = htmlBody.replace('{!Test__c.Notification_Date__c}', String.valueof(res.Notification_Date__c));
            htmlBody = htmlBody.replace('{!Test__c.Id}', res.Id);
            
            plainBody = plainBody.replace('{!Test__c.Name}',res.Name);
            plainBody = plainBody.replace('{!Test__c.Notification_Date__c}',String.valueof(res.Notification_Date__c));
            plainBody = plainBody.replace('{!Test__c.Id}', res.Id);
            
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            mail.setTemplateId(et.Id);
            mail.setTargetObjectId(res.OwnerId);
            mail.setSubject(et.Subject);
            mail.setHTMLBody(htmlBody);
            mail.setPlainTextBody(plainBody);
            mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
            mail.setUseSignature(false);
            allmsg.add(mail);
        }

if(allmsg.size() > 0 ){
            Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results = Messaging.sendEmail(allmsg);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're overwriting the values in `htmlBody` and `plainTextBody`, so this results in the merge fields being lost after the first record. Further, you already have a template Id, so you shouldn't need to set `subject`, `htmlBody` or `plainTextBody`. Use `setWhatId` instead.

```
for(Test__c res : finalResourceEmailList){
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    mail.setTemplateId(et.Id);
    mail.setTargetObjectId(res.OwnerId);
    main.setWhatId(res.Id);
    mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
    mail.setUseSignature(false);
    allmsg.add(mail);
}
```

Comment: I got the error "WhatId is not available for sending emails to UserIds"

Comment: thanks for your help, I have been able to solve the issue

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using a template ID, you don't need to set the body with all the merge fields. Just provide the object via `setWhatId`. Since you are sending to a User, you will need to use the `renderStoredEmailTemplate` to avoid the error "WhatId is not available for sending emails to UserIds".

```
for(Test__c res : finalResourceEmailList){
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = Messaging.renderStoredEmailTemplate(et.Id, res.OwnerId, res.Id);
    email.setTargetObjectId(res.OwnerId);
    mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
    mail.setUseSignature(false);
    allmsg.add(mail);
}
```

I ran into this issue myself recently, and this other answer was tremendously helpful.
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/144498